# pl/sql query to insert multiple rows using select statement

Tags: for-loop, plsql

I want to insert multiple rows into a table.

The query would be:

```
insert into temp(table_name,run_date,table_count)
select 'TABLE_A',sysdate,count(*) from A;

insert into temp(table_name,run_date,table_count)
select 'TABLE_B',sysdate,count(*) from B;


insert into temp(table_name,run_date,table_count)
select 'TABLE_C',sysdate,count(*) from C;
```

How do I write this in a loop using pl/sql?

Thanks,
Anju

Comment: Why do you need a loop? Why not `UNION` three queries and insert it at once?

Comment: If you don't want to hard-code A, B, C, you need to use dynamic sql (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE).

Answer (score 0):

For a variable list of tables, here's a script that reads the Oracle system table ALL_TABLES for a specified owner and inserts the counts into a temp table.

```
DECLARE

  -- Define a cursor to get the list of tables you want counts for.
  cursor c1 is
  select table_name
  from all_tables
  where owner = 'YOUR_OWNER_HERE';

  -- Dynamically created select.
  stmt varchar2(200);

BEGIN

  -- The cursor for loop implicitly opens and closes the cursor.
  for table_rec in c1
  loop
    -- dynamically build the insert statement.
    stmt := 'insert into temp(table_name,run_date,table_count) ';
    stmt := stmt || 'select ''' || table_rec.table_name || ''','''|| sysdate||''','|| 'count(*) from ' || table_rec.table_name;

    -- Execute the insert statement.
    execute immediate(stmt);

  end loop;
END;  
commit;
```